# ASP.NET MVC5 route to a div on a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to setup a route that's routes to a div on a page in my RouteConfig.cs file but doesn't work (HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden).

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}#{locId}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", locId = 
          "theDiv", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Can somebody help me out please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The URL fragment (the bit of a URL after the #) isn't sent to the web server. Unfortunately this means you can't use it for routing in MVC5.

Comment: Remove the illegal `#` (fragment) from the route definition. If you want to generate a link with a fragment, use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx) of `@Html.ActionLink()`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}#{HTMLElementId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, HTMLElementId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

this sets it as an optional parameter.

thanks

Comment: I put this above my Default route in the RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your route differently using this format :

```
url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}#{locid}",
```

Comment: how do you post your actions?  try this: return RedirectToAction()